# Strange /usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1 error - unknown argument '-wall'

Tags: ios7, xcode5, clang, osx-mavericks

I searched around and there are numerous posts with different arguments for clang, but I have not seen one related to '-wall'
Here is full stack:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-wall' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
ProcessPCH /var/folders/bt/x7t6pymn3vs_mykqfrpwhwgdgbmz8t/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.1-5B130a/Xcode/5.1-5B130a/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MyAppName-Prefix-axoyogsqgxeawmhjfylnspfdgfkm/MyAppName-Prefix.pch.pch MyAppName/MyAppName-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

I am running the latest Xcode Version 5.1 (5B130a)
I haven't change anything in the codebase lately, but I believe Xcode updated couple of days ago. I don't experience this on other projects that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the problem with the new version of clang that is provided with Xcode 5.1 Temporary solution for me was to downgrade to Xcode 5.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a mistyped gcc argument.  You probably want `-Weverything` instead.  See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-control-error-and-warning-messages

Comment: I don't think it's mistyped, as '-Wall' is mentioned in the link you provided: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas

Comment: If clang does include it, then you need to use a capital `W`, not a lowercase `w`.